# Show that the function from standard metric to discrete metric is discontinuous.

Tags: continuity, metric-spaces

Show that the function g:(R,d)->(R,d_0) where d_0 is the discrete metric, d is standard metric on R ie d(x,y)=|x-y| and g(x)=x^6 is discontinuous

So I think I'm meant to use epsilon-delta proof but I'm not really sure how to start it? Unless there is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose there exist $\delta >0$ such that $|x-0| <\delta$ implies $d_0(f(x),f(0))<1 $. Take $%x=\frac  1 n$ where $\frac  1 n <\delta$. Then we get $1<1$, a contradiction.